# Need to build entires sentences from an odd xml file splitted in tokens

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, nlp

I work on an NLP project with XSLT and i need to create sentences with the following XML doc :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cordial2xml>
<w><forme>la</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDFS</categorie></w><w><forme>grande</forme><lemme>grand</lemme><categorie>ADJFS</categorie></w><w><forme>douleur</forme><lemme>douleur</lemme><categorie>NCFS</categorie></w><w><forme>du</forme><lemme>du</lemme><categorie>DETDMS</categorie></w><w><forme>père</forme><lemme>père</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w><w><forme>duchesne</forme><lemme>duchesne</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w>
<w><forme>au sujet de</forme><lemme>au sujet de</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>la</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDFS</categorie></w><w><forme>mort</forme><lemme>mort</lemme><categorie>NCFS</categorie></w><w><forme>de</forme><lemme>de</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>marat</forme><lemme>marat</lemme><categorie>NPMS</categorie></w><w><forme>assassiné</forme><lemme>assassiner</lemme><categorie>VPARPMS</categorie></w><w><forme>à</forme><lemme>à</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w>
<w><forme>coups</forme><lemme>coup</lemme><categorie>NCMP</categorie></w><w><forme>de</forme><lemme>de</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>couteau</forme><lemme>couteau</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w><w><forme>par</forme><lemme>par</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>une</forme><lemme>un</lemme><categorie>DETIFS</categorie></w><w><forme>garce</forme><lemme>gars</lemme><categorie>NCFS</categorie></w><w><forme>du</forme><lemme>du</lemme><categorie>DETDMS</categorie></w><w><forme>calvados</forme><lemme>calvados</lemme><categorie>NCMIN</categorie></w><w><forme>,</forme><lemme>,</lemme><categorie>PCTFAIB</categorie></w>
<w><forme>dont</forme><lemme>dont</lemme><categorie>PRI</categorie></w><w><forme>l'</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDMS</categorie></w><w><forme>évêque</forme><lemme>évêque</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w><w><forme>fauchet</forme><lemme>fauchet</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w><w><forme>était</forme><lemme>être</lemme><categorie>VINDI3S</categorie></w><w><forme>le</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDMS</categorie></w><w><forme>directeur.ses</forme><lemme>directeur.ses</lemme><categorie>NCI</categorie></w>
<w><forme>bons</forme><lemme>bon</lemme><categorie>ADJMP</categorie></w><w><forme>avis</forme><lemme>avis</lemme><categorie>NCMIN</categorie></w><w><forme>aux</forme><lemme>au</lemme><categorie>DETDPIG</categorie></w><w><forme>braves</forme><lemme>brave</lemme><categorie>NCPIG</categorie></w><w><forme>sans</forme><lemme>sans</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>-culottes</forme><lemme>culotte</lemme><categorie>NCFP</categorie></w><w><forme>pour</forme><lemme>pour</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w>
<w><forme>qu'</forme><lemme>que</lemme><categorie>SUB</categorie></w><w><forme>ils</forme><lemme>il</lemme><categorie>PPER3P</categorie></w><w><forme>se</forme><lemme>se</lemme><categorie>PPER3S</categorie></w><w><forme>tiennent</forme><lemme>tenir</lemme><categorie>VINDP3P</categorie></w><w><forme>sur</forme><lemme>sur</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>leurs</forme><lemme>leur</lemme><categorie>DETPOSS</categorie></w><w><forme>gardes</forme><lemme>garde</lemme><categorie>NCFP</categorie></w><w><forme>,</forme><lemme>,</lemme><categorie>PCTFAIB</categorie></w>
<w><forme>attendu qu'</forme><lemme>attendu que</lemme><categorie>SUB</categorie></w><w><forme>il</forme><lemme>il</lemme><categorie>PPER3S</categorie></w><w><forme>y</forme><lemme>y</lemme><categorie>PPER3S</categorie></w><w><forme>a</forme><lemme>avoir</lemme><categorie>VINDP3S</categorie></w><w><forme>dans</forme><lemme>dans</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>paris</forme><lemme>pari</lemme><categorie>NCMP</categorie></w><w><forme>plusieurs</forme><lemme>plusieurs</lemme><categorie>ADJIND</categorie></w><w><forme>milliers</forme><lemme>millier</lemme><categorie>NCMP</categorie></w>
<w><forme>de</forme><lemme>de</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>tondus</forme><lemme>tondu</lemme><categorie>ADJMP</categorie></w><w><forme>de</forme><lemme>de</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>la</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDFS</categorie></w><w><forme>vendée</forme><lemme>vendée</lemme><categorie>NPFS</categorie></w><w><forme>qui</forme><lemme>qui</lemme><categorie>PRI</categorie></w><w><forme>ont</forme><lemme>avoir</lemme><categorie>VINDP3P</categorie></w><w><forme>la</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDFS</categorie></w><w><forme>patte</forme><lemme>patte</lemme><categorie>NCFS</categorie></w>
<w><forme>graissée</forme><lemme>graisser</lemme><categorie>VPARPFS</categorie></w><w><forme>pour</forme><lemme>pour</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w><w><forme>égorger</forme><lemme>égorger</lemme><categorie>VINF</categorie></w><w><forme>tous</forme><lemme>tout</lemme><categorie>ADJMP</categorie></w><w><forme>les</forme><lemme>le</lemme><categorie>DETDPIG</categorie></w><w><forme>bons</forme><lemme>bon</lemme><categorie>ADJMP</categorie></w><w><forme>citoyens</forme><lemme>citoyen</lemme><categorie>NCMP</categorie></w><w><forme>.</forme><lemme>.</lemme><categorie>PCTFORTE</categorie></w>
<w><forme>marat</forme><lemme>marat</lemme><categorie>NPMS</categorie></w><w><forme>n'</forme><lemme>ne</lemme><categorie>ADV</categorie></w><w><forme>est</forme><lemme>être</lemme><categorie>VINDP3S</categorie></w><w><forme>plus</forme><lemme>plus</lemme><categorie>ADV</categorie></w><w><forme>,</forme><lemme>,</lemme><categorie>PCTFAIB</categorie></w><w><forme>foutre.peuple</forme><lemme>foutre.peuple</lemme><categorie>NCI</categorie></w><w><forme>,</forme><lemme>,</lemme><categorie>PCTFAIB</categorie></w><w><forme>gémis</forme><lemme>gémir</lemme><categorie>VPARPMP</categorie></w><w><forme>,</forme><lemme>,</lemme><categorie>PCTFAIB</categorie></w>
<w><forme>pleure</forme><lemme>pleurer</lemme><categorie>VIMPP2S</categorie></w><w><forme>ton</forme><lemme>ton</lemme><categorie>DETPOSS</categorie></w><w><forme>meilleur</forme><lemme>meilleur</lemme><categorie>ADJMS</categorie></w><w><forme>ami</forme><lemme>ami</lemme><categorie>NCMS</categorie></w><w><forme>;</forme><lemme>;</lemme><categorie>PCTFORTE</categorie></w>
<w><forme>il</forme><lemme>il</lemme><categorie>PPER3S</categorie></w><w><forme>meurt</forme><lemme>mourir</lemme><categorie>VINDP3S</categorie></w><w><forme>martyr</forme><lemme>martyr</lemme><categorie>ADJMS</categorie></w><w><forme>de</forme><lemme>de</lemme><categorie>PREP</categorie></w>
</cordial2xml>
```

It's just a piece of this XML doc. From it, i need to construct sentences so i need to concatenate the forme nodes with space between and stop until a word where there is a point between (end of sentence) or only '.' For the last word cutted in 2 by the point, i need to keep the first one sustring before point on current sentence and the sustring after will be the begenning of a new sentence.
The problem is that, i don't know how to do that. I don't know if i have the create a template matching //w but i can't figure out with only word at the time so i need all the nodes forme until a node which frome contains '.' keeping the first substring forme which contains '.' in the current sentence and the sustring after '.' is the first word of a new sentence
Actually, for the first 2 sentences, i need the desired output :

```
<p>la grande douleur du pere duchesne au sujet de la mort de marat à coups de couteau par un gard du calvados, l'eveque fauchet etait le directeur.</p>

<p>bons avis au brave sans culottes pour que se tiennent sur leurs gardes, attendu qu'il a dans paris plusieurs milliers de tondus de la vendée qui ont la patte grasser pour egorger tous les bons citoyens.<p>
etc...
```

At the begenning, i would like to apply a recursive template to create each sentence but how to keep the following word cutted but the point in the next sentence.
I could also use a template matching //w but i don't know how to deal with the p in xslt code tags
I could captured all nodes between the current one and the node where the forme contains a '.' like this w[1]/following-sibling::*[not(contains(./forme, '.'))][1] (grouping node between the first w and the last w with forme contains '.' and recursively. The absolute first forme is the begenning of the first sentence.
Do you have any idea to achieve my task ? I'm lost. I don't want necessary a code but a method.
If you have pieces of code, it's better for sure.
Thx a lot.

Comment: I see no periods in the input that you have provided. And the output you show is completely different from the input. That's extremely unhelpful for understanding what you want to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two passes: first, construct an entire paragraph by joining all the words, separated by a space. Then split the paragraph into sentences using the period character as the delimiter.

Since you said (in another question) that you are using the `libxslt` processor, you can use an extension function to perform the second pass.

Here is a simplified example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <word>Joe</word>
    <word>waited</word>
    <word>for</word>
    <word>the</word>
    <word>train.</word>
    <word>The</word>
    <word>train</word>
    <word>was</word>
    <word>late.Meanwile</word>
    <word>Mary</word>
    <word>and</word>
    <word>Samantha</word>
    <word>took</word>
    <word>the</word>
    <word>bus.</word>
    <word>Orphan</word>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="para">
        <xsl:for-each select="word">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize($para, '.')">
            <sentence>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
                <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
            </sentence>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <sentence>Joe waited for the train.</sentence>
  <sentence>The train was late.</sentence>
  <sentence>Meanwile Mary and Samantha took the bus.</sentence>
  <sentence>Orphan.</sentence>
</output>
```

---

### Added:

> Actually i use Saxon 9.

Well, then you can simplify this further to:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="para">
        <xsl:value-of select="word"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($para, '\.')">
            <sentence>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
                <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
            </sentence>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thx for your response Michael. Actually i use Saxon 9. It's far better imo. The problem is the XML file is oddly built. I don't know how to manage my data. There is the root cordial2xml and only w childs. So i don't know how to deal with that. Your simplified example and your output is exactly what  i want but my XML file is not like that.
If i would to concatenate all the forme/text() with, how should it be done ? I'll start by the beginning and i will complete by myself. Sorry for my ignorance but i've started XSLT 3 days ago.

Comment: @EtienneArmangau You need to have at least a rudimentary knowledge of XSLT before you can ask questions here.

Comment: I progress every day but fortunately, there are people like you to help me. I went from Python and Assembly and XSLT needs to think differently. At the moment, I haven't yet understood the main part that's right. By the way, thx for your help. I really appreciate it.